# Postgres column "distance" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a literal inside my `select` query, and at the end I'm trying to use `having` to find results that have a `distance < 50000`.

Coming from a `MySql` background, I'd think that this query *should* work.

```
SELECT "description", 
       "location", 
       ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_MakePoint(-126.4,45.32)) AS "distance" 
FROM "news_agencies" AS "news_agencies" 
HAVING distance < 50000;
```

I also tried adding quotes around the `having >>>"distance"<<<` text. If I remove '`having distance < 50000`', my query runs fine and calculates the distance. Here is my error:

```
column "distance" does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use alias name in a `having` clause. Try like this:

```
select * from
(
SELECT "description", "location", 
ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_MakePoint(-126.4,45.32)) AS "distance" 
FROM "news_agencies" AS "news_agencies") t
where distance < 50000;
```